# Modify this regex expression so that it only accepts characters given with this condition

Tags: regex, angular, angular7

I have a custom validator in my Angular 7 application.  I need it to only accept certain characters, however, it is still accepting characters that are not included in my condition.

My custom validator:

```
  static addressFormat(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } {
    const isValidAddress = (/^([a-zA-Z0-9,.#-@%&'])([a-zA-Z0-9,.#-@%&'\s/]?)+$/).test(control.value);
    return isValidAddress ? null : { addressFormat: true };
  }
```

The first character cannot be an empty space, which is working fine.
After that, the only characters it should accept are the following:

```
Numbers 0 to 9

Uppercase letters A-Z (you will see the expression accepts lowercase, but ive taken care of that with making each form control value uppercase inside the input tag)

period .

apostrophe '

hyphen -

comma ,

hashtag #

at sign @

percentage %

ampersand &

slash /

spaces
```

The problem is, I can enter characters like * ) ( + : ; = > < ? and it will consider those valid.  How can I modify this validator to make sure those are excluded?

Comment: As mentioned with @shawnt00 the issue was the - between # and @.

Modified regex is:
(/^([a-zA-Z0-9,.#@%&'-])([a-zA-Z0-9,.#@%&'\s/-]?)+$/).test(control.value);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this character class. Yours is permitting a range from `#` to `@`, rather than just those three individual characters. That's why the bad ones are slipping through:

```
 [-a-zA-Z0-9,.#@%&']
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue, #-@ was accepting special characters within that range.